# Complicated search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have defined a `PostSchema` as follows. A `post` is written by an `author`, and can be read by many people: `lastOpens` is an array of `{ time: ... , userId: ... }`.

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String }
    author: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
    lastOpens: { type: Array, default: [] }
})
```

Now, I want to write a static method that returns all the posts read by one user:

```
PostSchema.statics.postsOpenedByUser = function (userId, cb) {
  // need to go through all the posts, and check their `lastOpens`. 
  // If `userId` is in `userId` of a `lastOpen`, then count the post in  
}
```

What I know is the methods like `find({ ... })` of MongoDB. But I don't know how to specify a more complicated search like mine.

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1:** I tried to use `$where` operator as follows, it did not work:

```
PostSchema.statics.postsOpenedByUser = function (userId, cb) {
    return this.find({ $where: function () {
        var index = -1; 
        for (var i = 0; i < this.lastOpens.length; i++)
            if (this.lastOpens[i].userId === userId) { index = i; break }
        return !(index === -1)
}}, cb)
```

Is there anything we could not do inside `$where`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongo's [query an array of embedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/).

In your case it will look something like :

```
PostSchema.statics.postsOpenedByUser = function (userId, cb) {
    return this.find( { "lastOpens.userId" : userId }, cb );
}
```

This will return all posts that have userId in the `lastOpens`